# Using files within a Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I'm currently developing a custom installer for a script for After Effects that I have developed. My plan is to place the files that need to be copied into a certain directory to be within the JAR file of the installer that I am making.

My question is this. Where within the Java project structure should I place the files? (I'm using Eclipse if that helps). Secondly, how might I access and copy these files to a custom location on the end users' computer? Any code samples would be much appreciated, as I'm used to developing in HTML and JavaScript. Thanks.

-- As a side note, I know variants of this question have been posted before. However, these have not been particularly specific to this question, so therefore have had a short life of use.

Comment: you should keep the file in the same file your java source code would be in, usually the src folder

Answer (score 0):

Files in a jar are read-only *resources*. One can get them with

```
ClassInJar.getResource("/.../.../readme.html")
```

`getResourceAsStream` or such.

Nice is also the external form:

```
Path path = Paths.get("jar:file:/ ... install.jar!/.../.../readme.html");
Files.copy(path, ...);
```

Using getResource inside an eclipse application, where the jar might not be on the class path (even not desired to be on the class path) is not feasible, so use the **jar:** protocol to easily copy files out of a zip file system.

Comment: Did you mean `Paths.get(URI.create("jar:file:/ ... install.jar!/.../.../readme.html"));`?

Comment: @VGR in general I do it via a URI so that might be the way to go. was your comment a polite "needs a URI instead of a String"?

Comment: Pretty much.  From what I can tell, the Paths.get(String...) method requires path components.  I would expect the passing of a string containing a URI to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can technically put them wherever you want. The convention is here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_project_layout so src/main/resources probably makes sense depending on what you're actually referring to.

Copying a file can be done in a lot of ways here's one. (Stolen from here: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/file/4-ways-to-copy-file-in-java/)

```
private static void copyFileUsingJava7Files(File source, File dest)
        throws IOException {
    Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());
}
```

Comment: So if I put '/src/com/mypackage/resources/file.txt' to access the file, creating an instance of the file object with that directory,  that would work?

Comment: The convention would be package/src/main/resources . Would it work is pretty generic, but could it work? Absolutely depending on your implementation. Basically I'm saying post your code and we can help from there.